# 400 SELECT queries to populate php grid

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in my database, table A and table B. I need to populate a visual grid of 20x20 squares, 400 squares in total. I just need to read the data, not insert or update.

What my script does is does FOR loop through each grid id, querys table A to see if data exists, and if it does, it does another mysql query to pulls data from table B.

As you can imagine this is using a lot of resources (400 requests). I'm not the best at PHP, but wondered if anyone knew of a better way to do this?

Note: I can't combine the 2 tables, it has to be separate.

```
<table width="500" height="500" background="images/map.png"><?
$plot = 1;
for ($plot_y = 1; $plot_y <= 20; $plot_y++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($plot_x = 1; $plot_x <= 20; $plot_x++) {
      $sql_result5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM turfs WHERE plot ='$plot'", $db);
      if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result5) != 0) {
          $rs5 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result5);

          $nogo = 0; // SET COLOR TO rs5[color]
      } else {
          $nogo = 1;
      }
?><td width="23" height="23"><?php
      if ($nogo == 0) {
          $sql_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM properties WHERE plot = '$plot'", $db);
          if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result) > 0) {
              $rs = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result);

              echo "<img src=$rs[image]>";

          }
      }
      echo "</td>";
      $plot = $plot + 1;
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
?></table>
```

Comment: subselects to the rescue? At least then this would be one request only - no idea if it's really faster on the db thought.

Comment: You need to insert or update?

Comment: can you provide both select statements and desired output?

Comment: @Alfonso Rubalcava Where do you see anything related to inserting/updating?!? Even before the edit of the post? Populating - selecting from db!

Comment: @Bakudan Select from A... insert or update in B. This **is** the question.

Comment: *"querys table A to see if data exists, and if it does, it does another mysql query to pulls data from table B."* Why 2 tables? Can't you just check directly in B if the data exists or not? I don't see the use for A here.

Comment: @netcoder: because you (or anyone else here except OP) don't know what is the data structure and relationship between both tables.

Comment: @Mchl: I figured that much, hence my question.

Comment: You can also check this [PHP Grid Framework](http://phpgrid.org) solution. It's simple to use than above. Disclaimer: I work for www.phpgrid.org.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that much queries will take a lot of memory. There is a "trick" to optimize multiple queries that are alike - [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

You have 2 tables thah sounds like you need a [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) (if you are not using such).

Then you can use some caching if the data is not updating very often.

There are a lot of thing that could be optimized ...

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your table structure the best we can do is guess at it but following might give you some fresh ideas to work with.

The gist of it would be to

- select the GridID's and the related data with one select statement
- loop over the results of this statement to fill your grid

#### SQL Statement (edited)

```
SELECT t.plot AS plot
       , t.plot MOD 20 AS plot_x
       , FLOOR(t.plot / 20) AS plot_y
       , CASE WHEN p.plot IS NULL THEN 'free' ELSE 'used' END
FROM   turfs AS t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN properties AS p ON p.plot = t.plot
```

Comment: im useless at PHP so help me clarify, how would i call data from this, eg the 'image' field from the properties table. Would it be $rs[properties.image] ?

Comment: and does this sql remove the need for the FOR loop in my code?

Comment: @user880356 - it would remove the need for 400 queries but it would still require one loop (io two). How this is done in PHP is also beyond me.